# Is there any way to protect executable's resources?

Tags: python, executable

Is there any way to protect my **executable file's resources** such as .png and more  which i used to make **button designs** etc in my python executable. Like if someone mess with them the **executable** will fail.
I mean like **zipping** or something which user cannot read or write but program or executable can.

Comment: Why bother? A suitably interested party can circumvent any protection of yours anyway.

Comment: effectively: no. you could try but visible elements can't really be protected since everybody can simply screenshot it...

Answer (score 1):

You could protect them with a checksum (Like SHA-2), if the resource is changed, checksum will be changed, and you can emit an error.

Another approach would be to load it from a blob embedded into the program as byte array. This approach is worse, but it would help to prevent accidental tampering.

**But: As soon as somebody, with enough interest downloads your program, everything you try to protect your resources, will fail**

Answer (score 1):

This can get pretty complicated fast, what you're looking for obfuscation.

You could go as simple as just checking an SHA1 checksum of a file you load to make sure it hasn't been altered, to cryptographically encoding your source to prevent targeted reverse engineering attacks.

I would recommend the following websites to read more about this:

https://pyob.oxyry.com/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

But overall, this is a topic which is a bit too complex for a simple answer.